# How do I change transition duration for paper-dropdown?

Tags: polymer

From Polymer Dropdown menu: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/paper-dropdown.html

The default transition is `core-transistion-fade` but it loads very slow. I would like to change the transition duration. How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set the `duration` attribute to your paper-dropdown to make the transition faster

```
<paper-dropdown duration="300"></paper-dropdown>
```

Duration default value is 500

Hope this help :)